# I have code that works with 1 video. How do I make it work with multiple videos?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code that sends data back to Google Analytics for 1 video.  How do I convert the code to work with multiple videos?  I need to know the proper way to adapt this code to not just 1 video but multiple videos.  I had to repost my code since I don't know how else to do it.  The code is below;

```
    <video id="v1" src="/v1.mp4" width="400px" height="200px" controls />
<video id="v2" src="/v2.mp4" width="400px" height="200px" controls />


<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
  var videoId, dur, quarter, stat;

  function init() {
    for (var video of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
      video.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false);
      video.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false);
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false);
    }
  }

  function setKeyFrames(duration) {
    if (dur) {
      return;
    }
    dur = duration;
    quarter = duration / 4;
  }

  function videoTimeUpdate(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    var curTime = videoId.currentTime;
    if (curTime >= quarter && curTime < quarter * 2 && stat !== 1) {
      gtag('event', 'Watched Video', {
        'event_category': 'Video',
        'event_label': 'Watched 25% of ' + videoId.id
      });
      stat = 1;

    } else if (curTime >= quarter * 2 && curTime < quarter * 3 && stat !== 2) {
      gtag('event', 'Watched Video', {
        'event_category': 'Video',
        'event_label': 'Watched 50% of ' + videoId.id
      });
      stat = 2;

    } else if (curTime >= quarter * 3 && curTime < dur && stat !== 3) {
      gtag('event', 'Watched Video', {
        'event_category': 'Video',
        'event_label': 'Watched 75% of ' + videoId.id
      });
      stat = 3;

    }
  }

  function videoPlay(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    gtag('event', 'Watched Video', {
      'event_category': 'Video',
      'event_label': 'Video Played Is ' + videoId.id
    })
    setKeyFrames(this.duration);

  }


  function videoEnd(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    stat = 4;
    gtag('event', 'Watched Video', {
        'event_category': 'Video',
        'event_label': 'Watched ALL of ' + videoId.id
      });

  }



})();


</script>
```

Comment: It works for a single mp4 ona  home page for example.  But what if there were 2 mp4 videos on the home page.  Or 5 movies.  I just want to adapt it those situations.

Comment: I tried to paste the code here but there's too many characters

Comment: I need help specifically with the javascript code so it can work with no matter how many movies there are.

Comment: I edited my post using the correct code formatting.  hopefully that works

Comment: Hi & Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please indent your code correctly, and try to reduce its length as much as possible. The cleaner and shorter it is, the easier it will be for anyone to help you :-) If you want to look at pro-tips on how to ask, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('video')` to get all the videos.
Then iterate them to `addEventListener`s.
Then, in event handles, use `event.target` to get the video element.

See the snippet below, I added `console.log` to visualize callbacks:

```js
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
  var videoId, dur, quarter, stat;

  function init() {
    for (var video of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
      video.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false);
      video.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false);
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false);
    }
  }

  function setKeyFrames(duration) {
    if (dur) {
      return;
    }
    dur = duration;
    quarter = duration / 4;
  }

  function videoTimeUpdate(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    var curTime = videoId.currentTime;
    if (curTime >= quarter && curTime < quarter * 2 && stat !== 1) {
      gtag('event', 'Test 2 - User Watched 25% of Video', {
        'event_category': 'video played is the monkey category',
        'event_label': 'video played is the label'
      });
      stat = 1;
      console.log(videoId.id + ' 25% watched');
    } else if (curTime >= quarter * 2 && curTime < quarter * 3 && stat !== 2) {
      gtag('event', 'Test 2 - User Watched 50% of Video', {
        'event_category': 'video played is the monkey category',
        'event_label': 'video played is the label'
      });
      stat = 2;
      console.log(videoId.id + ' 50% watched');
    } else if (curTime >= quarter * 3 && curTime < dur && stat !== 3) {
      gtag('event', 'Test 2 - User Watched 75% of Video', {
        'event_category': 'video played is the monkey category',
        'event_label': 'video played is the label'
      });
      stat = 3;
      console.log(videoId.id + ' 75% watched');
    }
  }

  function videoPlay(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    gtag('event', 'Test 2 - User Played Video', {
      'event_category': 'video played is the monkey category',
      'event_label': 'video played is the label'
    })
    setKeyFrames(this.duration);
    console.log(videoId.id + ' start');
  }


  function videoEnd(e) {
    var videoId = e.target;
    stat = 4;
    gtag('event', 'Test 2 - User Watched ALL of Video', {
      'event_category': 'video played is the monkey category',
      'event_label': 'video played is the label'
    });
    console.log(videoId.id + ' end');
  }
  
  // placeholder
  function gtag(){}
  
})();
```

```css
video {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw
}
```

```html
<video id="v1" src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-1.webm" controls></video>
<video id="v2" src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-2.webm" controls></video>
<video id="v3" src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-3.webm" controls></video>
<video id="v4" src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-5.webm" controls></video>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this.  I must be missing something.  Its not sending the info back to Google Analytics events.  Although I do see it working when I click on Run Code snippet.  Could you push me in the right direction here.

Comment: @ImASkuller, remove my `// placeholder  function gtag(){}`

Comment: I have a mac.  I pulled up the console on my mac and I can't see the results as I see them on this web page.

Comment: great.  I believe its working now.  Let me do some more testing and then I'll confirm it here.

Comment: i'm having some issues getting the data over to analytics.

Comment: I want to post all of my code but I just don't know how to do it

Comment: @ImASkuller, what kind of issues?

Comment: the only way I could show you my current code (based on the code you sent me) is by reposting it to my original message.  Please look at my original message.  When I go to GA I don't see the events firing.

Comment: @ImASkuller, GA issue is out of your original question scope. If your question has been answered, please accept the answer. If you have another problem -- feel free to post another question.

Comment: sorry havent been here for a while